# ionic4 back button does not appear

Tags: ionic4

Trying to get back-button to show up in component.html header but no joy. Appreciate any ideas. This is the code from [ionic docs](http://https:/https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button)

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start" icon="arrow-back">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try with my code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar mode="ios" color="light">
   <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button size="small" shape="round" color="dark" text="">
   </ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>
    Dashboard
  </ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still trying to work through the problem. Seems more complex if it is in a modal.

Answer (score 0):

Your back button does not appear if there are no pages in the stack. If you want your back button show then use this.

```
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button name="arrow-back" (click)="backFuntionName()">
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

It shows always on the header.

```
   <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
```

use this when you go to the next page and return back.